# DaVinci Resolve 17 doesn't show video and shows black screen on imported multimedia

Tags: davinci-resolve

DaVinci Resolve 17 doesn't show video and shows black screen on imported multimedia.
I have VivoBook Pro X580VD, Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-7300HQ bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Kaby Lake, Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 630 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0
chip ID: 8086:591b
Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia
v: 460.32.03 bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1c8d
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting,nvidia
unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.32.03
direct render: Yes
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-64-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6      wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
[image]

Comment: There’s no video on V1, only an audio track on A1.  What happens when you use the edit page instead of the cut page?  If you double-click on the footage in the edit page media pool to view it in the source monitor, will the video play there?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Tried many thing but it's the same. Anyone got it working?